# Appending 2D arrays starting with a dummy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The data in my case are 2D arrays available in multiple files. In the end, I would like to append these 2D arrays row-wise. For example, say `fileA` contains

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and `fileB` contains

```
7 8 9
0 1 2
```

I would like the resulting operation to be

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
0 1 2
```

There are multiple ways to concatenate arrays `A` (contents of `fileA`) and `B` (contents of `fileB`). However in my case, there are multiple files and I am looping over each file and want to save the data into a single array `A`. For this, I have assigned `A=[[]]` and tried multiple numpy operations such as `append()`, `concatenate()`, and `vstack()`. The prime issue for me is that these methods throw an error on the very first loop where size of `A` is `0x0` and the array to be appended has `2x3` size. How to achieve this pythonically? I am open for `numpy` and `pandas` solutions. The objective to append these multiple arrays row-wise into one. Therefore, it does not even have to be starting with dummy array. Any solution is appreciated.

PS: If I assign explicitly `A` with contents of `fileA` and then append contents of `fileB, fileC, etc.` to `A` *in a loop*, then I do not face any issue.

Comment: What's the problem then? I think appending to an already created array is normal.

Comment: A more beautiful way is to read all the arrays into list and concatenate contents of the list at the final stage. This eats more memory though, obviously

Comment: did you try a list comprehension ```lis = [file_content for file_content in files]``` and then concatenate the arrays?

Comment: @sos Thanks. It works! However, I need to have a column added for each array. So still thinking how to get this done in a single for loop.

Comment: If `A` starts as (0,3) shape, you shouldn't have dimension problems.  Pay attention to the error message (including traceback) when you get these concatenate errors.  But as others show doing one concatenate on a whole list is better than repeated ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to collect the files first in a list comprehension

```
lis = [file_content for file_content in files]
```

if you need to add a column to file_content then you can do it using `np.c_[ file_content, np.ones(file_content.shape[0]) ]`  :

```
lis = [np.c_[file_content , np.ones(file_content.shape[0])] for file_content in files]
```

here you add a column full of ones (you can put any array you like instead of `np.ones(file_content.shape[0])` provided that they have the same number of rows